# opengl rotate an object to set its correct face before render on screen

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glm-math

I am loading an object through an obj file in opengl using GLM Library but it comes out on the screen upside down. Also i am providing a capability to user so he can rotate all the objects accordingly by mouse too. e.g. zoom and zoom in and rotate with y axis.

Problem is i dont know how to rotate the object first to make its face according to what i need. After that i want to draw this object and offcourse at that time mouse can play its role to rotate it.

my draw function contain the following code

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(m_fPosX, m_fPosY,-m_fZoom);
glRotatef(m_fRotX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);//these two for mouse movement
glRotatef(m_fRotY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotated(180,0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glColor3f(0.90f,0.90f,0.90f);
glmDraw(m_p3dModel,GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL); 

glPopMatrix();
```

here rotate functions are all dependent on mouse movement but if it get load upside down i dont know how to first make my object face right direction and then allow it in this draw function...Which means i need to set its face before calling this draw function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glRotatef(m_fRotY, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

should be

```
glRotatef(m_fRotY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

copy/paste is the mother of many evils :o)

For transformation / projection / model view tutorial : check [link](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html)

Comment: this is not the answer , okay that was some typo mistake but my question is how to set the direction of an object before rendering it into its draw function. Suppose if an object is upside down at the time of loading then how i can fix its face before render it on the screen...beside this rotation that you point is for mouse movement at the runtime of draw function

Comment: @wolvornePk, it is hard to debug why it is upside down as the values of m_fZoom (& reasons why you negate them) is not known. Can you give more info about the initial values of the variables.

Comment: i am using GLM library to load a 3d object which was made in 3dmax. But when i display it on the screen it comes upside down. other than that i want my mouse to act like an observer e.g. like i can zoom and rotate the entire objects on runtime. Beside this object there are so many other objects as well and every object is connected inside the scene so if i zoom by mouse then it shows each model according to zoom or if i use my mouse for roatation then all models get rotate. The mouse works fine but my object which i am loading i need to make its face and direction correct

Comment: i am sure i am doing some mistake but i will appreciate if you can help me to identify , please ask more question if i am not able to explain more clear.

Comment: What is the initial values of m_fPosX, m_fPosY and m_fZoom when you load the model.

Comment: m_fPosX = 0.0f;  
 m_fPosY = 0.0f;  
 m_fZoom = 5.0f; 

These are the initial values

Comment: How are you setting up the projection matrix ? can you add that snippet to the original question please. The code for the setup will be after glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);